# Configur a virtual box Interface, Which I want to survive reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, virtualbox

I want to configure an interface for the virtual box, which is installed within my ubuntu machine. When i create it manually it works:

```
vboxmanage hostonlyif create
vboxmanage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.56.1
```

by checking ifconfig, It is there :

I want to make these changes survive a reboot and set automatically during system startup.For that what i did is:

`sudo mkdir /opt/systemd/` then `sudo mkdir /opt/systemd/` then `sudo nano /opt/systemd/vboxhostonly` and copy the following code into the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
vboxmanage hostonlyif create
vboxmanage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.56.1
```

then Ctrl + X to exit , Y to save and enter to write file.

Then I make the file executable

`cd /opt/systemd/` then `sudo chmod a+x vboxhostonly`

the I create a service so

```
sudo touch /etc/systemd/system/vboxhostonlynic.service
```

Then I Edit the file by typing `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/vboxhostonlynic.service` and then typing in:

```
Description=Setup VirtualBox Hostonly Adapter
After=vboxdrv.service
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/opt/systemd/vboxhostonly
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

then Ctrl + X to exit , Y to save and enter to write file.

Now to install the service and ensure it loads at boot time I type:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable vboxhostonlynic.service
```

But when i reboot the machine the interface is not there, any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Do these changes to the adapter persist if you do them via the GUI?

Comment: Yes, they do, Thugh when i reboot the machine then they are not there.